# Ignore path outside base url in Angular 9 Router

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a SPA built with `React Router` and I have a page with an `Angular` app.
Everything is working fine, except the URL routes after accessing the `Angular` app.

The application runs on URL `http://localhost:7100/contextRoot`. I have multiple `React` pages for example:

- `http://localhost:7100/contextRoot/page1`
- `http://localhost:7100/contextRoot/page2`

And the routing in these works fine.
When I access the `Angular` application in `http://localhost:7100/contextRoot/angularApp` I can navigate throught `Angular` pages, for example:

- `http://localhost:7100/contextRoot/angularApp/page1`
- `http://localhost:7100/contextRoot/angularApp/page2`

I can use the back button in the browser and it works fine.

The problem is when I go again to `React` pages, the back button is not working because the `Angular Router` is also interfering.

This is my `Angular routing` configuration

```
const routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'angularApp/page1', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'angularApp/page1', component: Page1Component },
  { path: 'angularApp/page2', component: Page2Component },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I have the `base url` inside the React component where the Angular application runs:
`<base href={"contextRoot/angularApp"}/>`

How can I say to `Angular routing` to ignore and do NOTHING for URLs outside the `base url` ?

Comment: did you come with a solution @rMonteiro ?

Comment: @Maelig our solution was not using a SPA, but a two Page Application. All pages developed in React are inside a SPA, then we have a different page/template for the Angular app

Comment: After digging and digging, I opened an issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/50733

I provide in this issue the solution we are using to ignore routes outside our APP_BASE_HREF